# Limit of the $\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}$ when $(x, y) \to (0, 1)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How do i find the limit of the function $\frac{\sin(xy)}{x}$ as $(x, y)$  approaches $(0,1)$. I've tried to show, that the limit doesn't exist by picking some directions, but in all of them the limit was 1. What's the key in such a problems?

Comment: divide and multiply by $y$. Can you conclude something now?

Comment: No, the limit is _not_ $1$ in every direction.\

Comment: If you've found that the limit is 1 in all directions, maybe change approach and show that the limit _does_ exist?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the fact that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{\sin(xy)}x=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}y\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}=1,$$since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$.

More generally, $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}x=y_0$.